# PHP Get values from unknown numbers of text input

Tags: php, html, arrays, variables, input

I have a div in my page called `.highlights`.
In this div I have a unknown numbers of text input(`<input type="text" />`). It can range from 0 to unknown.

When someone clicks at submit, I want to store in PHP all the values of the inputs, into one variable called `myHighlights`. The values must be seperated by `;`

Comment: show us your tried code and submit form.

Comment: That is just the problem, I don´t know how to start

Comment: why not give the name to the filed? `<input type="text" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="unlimited[]" />

if( isset($_POST['submit_button']) ) {
   // Skip blank values
   $unlimited = array_filter( $_POST['unlimited'] );
   $myHighlights = implode(';', $unlimited);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you'll have to assign names to the controls so they get sent together with the rest of of the form. Please have a look at the [How do I create arrays in a HTML `<form>`?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) entry of the PHP FAQ for a nifty trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST)
{    
    $myHighlights = implode(';',$_POST);
    print_r($myHighlights);
}
```